# Getting jqGrid group column header values

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jquery 1.7.1. I am using group headers in jqGrid. i can get the column names using this code `$("#_My_Grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','colNames');`. Like this how can i get group header column names? i have shown group headers in my grid by using this code

```js
$("#_My_Grid").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
    useColSpanStyle: false, 
    groupHeaders:[   
        {startColumnName: 'amount', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: 'Price'},
        {startColumnName: 'closed', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: 'Shipping'}
    ]
});
```

I just want the values **Price,Shipping**. Can anybody resolve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options of of `setGroupHeaders` method will be saved in internal `groupHeader` option of jqGrid. So you can use the following code to access the values "Price" and "Shipping":

```js
var groupHeadersOptions = $("#_My_Grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "groupHeader"));
alert(groupHeadersOptions.groupHeaders[0].titleText); // displays "Price"
alert(groupHeadersOptions.groupHeaders[1].titleText); // displays "Shipping"
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thanks a lot... it works fine. I did the same thing but instead of groupHeader i tried groupHeaders. Thats why i have strucked...